# Add and remove classes depending on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to add and remove classes depending on whether the user scrolls down or up. So far I tried this with wheelDelta event. There is no scrollbar, the page uses 100vw and 100vw with overflow hidden. I want to achieve something similar to this: http://www.sound-of-change.com/#/intro/.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="item-1"></div>
<div class="item-2"></div>
<div class="item-3"></div>
<div class="item-4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

So whenever a user scrolls I want to be able to add and remove classes for each time someone scrolls down or up.

For example, the user is able to scroll down or up 4 times. And actually goes up or down (depending on the scroll direction) in the actions list.

Default: Situation 0

Scroll down once -> Situation 1

Scroll down again -> Situation 2

But if the users scrolls up now -> Situation 1 will be triggered

Scroll down again -> Back to situation 2

Scroll down again -> Situation 3

So far I only managed to trigger an event on scroll up and down, but that's it. Example:

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
              $(".cd-background-wrapper").css({'-webkit-filter': "grayscale(0%)"});
      $(".logo-text").removeClass("hide-logo");
      $(".logo-img").removeClass("come-closer");
    }
    else{
      $(".cd-background-wrapper").css({'-webkit-filter': "grayscale(100%)"});
      $(".logo-text").addClass("hide-logo");
      $(".logo-img").addClass("come-closer");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter to know which situation you are, something like this:

```js
var count = 1;

$("body").on('mousewheel', function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
    count -= 1;
  } else {
    count += 1;
  }
  if (count < 1) count = 1;
  if (count > 4) count = 4;

  switch (count) {
    case 1:
      // do something
      break;
    case 2:
      // do something
      break;
    case 3:
      // do something
      break;
    case 4:
      // do something
      break;
  }

  // Just a example that it works
  $("#wrapper").attr("data-slide", count);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

[data-slide="1"] {
  background-color: red;
}

[data-slide="2"] {
  background-color: green;
}

[data-slide="3"] {
  background-color: blue;
}

[data-slide="4"] {
  background-color: orange;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" data-slide="1"></div>
```

Comment: Wow this is great, thanks! Learned a lot from this. Just have one question: How do I make sure that the default state = count 1, and that scrolling back up goes back to 1. Now the default state doesn't have a count, as soon as you scroll it goes to count = 1, but it is not able to go back to count = 0.

Comment: This line `if (count < 1) count = 1;` ensures that the counter never will be lower than 0.

Comment: Thanks, I got it exactly as I want now.